# Gradient and Hessian of Matrix Least Squares with Squared Frobenius Norm Regularization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, least-squares

I want to find the Gradeint and Hessian of the following function, $F(\mathbf{S}) = \frac{1}{2}\Vert \mathbf{M} - \mathbf{K_2SK_1^T}\Vert _F^2+\frac{1}{2}\Vert\mathbf{S}\Vert_F^2$.
My try: Using trace formula for Frobenius norm, $F(\mathbf{X})$ can be writen as

$Grad(\mathbf{S}) =\frac{\partial}{\partial{S}}f(\mathbf{S})=\mathbf{K_2^T}(\mathbf{K_2SK_1^T}-\mathbf{M})\mathbf{K_1}+\mathbf{S}$
(cookbook eqn [70]&[84],updated accordding to greg's comments)

$Hess(\mathbf{S}) =\frac{\partial}{\partial{S}}Grad(\mathbf{S})=\mathbf{K_1^TK_1K_2^TK_2}+\mathbf{I}$

I got there results according to my understanding of the matrix cookbook. But obviously it's wrong.
e.g. :$ K_2(5000,256)$,$ K_1(32,256)$,$ M(5000,1)$, $ S(256,256)$. In Grad(S),the dimensions are not matched for multiplication.

I'm not, particularly, sure about the chain rule in the Grad step whether I can write this. Please help me to get out of this confusion.

Comment: Notice that with your dimension, $F(S)$ is not well-defined, since you cannot add $M$ and $K_2MK_1^T$

Comment: Fix the dimensions so that the #columns of $M$ match the #rows of $K_1$. Then your gradient can be salvaged by moving $K_2^T$ to the front, i.e. $$K_2^T(K_2SK_1^T-M)K_1+S$$ but the Hessian is more difficult since it is a 4th-order tensor, not a matrix.

Comment: @greg Can I move any term freely? How to get this final result?

Comment: No, you cannot move terms around. I was merely indicating the correct expression for the gradient. Somewhere in your calculation, you swapped the order of those two matrix terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the trace/Frobenius product as
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)={\rm Tr}(AB^T)$$
which make the Frobenius norm into a product
$$\|X\|_F^2 = X:X$$
Next, define the matrix
$$A=K_2SK_1^T-M$$
Write the cost function using the new notation and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
F &= \tfrac{1}{2}S:S + \tfrac{1}{2}A:A \\
dF &= S:dS + A:dA \\
 &= S:dS + A:K_2\,dS\,K_1^T \\
 &= S:dS + K_2^TAK_1:dS \\
 &= (S + K_2^TAK_1):dS \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial S}
 &= (S + K_2^TAK_1) 
\;=\; G\quad\big({\rm the\,gradient}\big) \\
}$$
[Flatten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the various matrices into vectors.
$$\eqalign{
s &= {\rm vec}(S) \\
a &= {\rm vec}(A) = (K_1\otimes K_2)s \\
}$$
Then vectorize $G$ and calculate its gradient (the Hessian).
$$\eqalign{
 g &= {\rm vec}(S + K_2^TAK_1) \\
   &= s + (K_1^T\otimes K_2^T) a&\big({\rm the\,vectorized\,gradient}\big)  \\
   &= \Big(I + (K_1\otimes K_2)^T(K_1\otimes K_2)\Big)s \\
dg &= \Big(I + (K_1\otimes K_2)^T(K_1\otimes K_2)\Big)ds \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}
 &= \Big(I + (K_1\otimes K_2)^T(K_1\otimes K_2)\Big)
\;=\; H\quad&\big({\rm the\,Hessian}\big) \\
H&\in {\mathbb R}^{256^2\times 256^2} \\
}$$

#### Update

You can also calculate the Hessian in its un-flattened tensor form
$$\eqalign{
dG &= dS + K_2^TdA\,K_1 \\
   &= dS + K_2^TK_2\,dS\,K_1^TK_1 \\
   &= \Big({\Omega} + K_2^TK_2{\Omega}K_1^TK_1\Big):dS \\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}
   &= \Big({\Omega} + K_2^TK_2{\Omega}K_1^TK_1\Big)
 \;=\; {\cal H} \\
{\cal H}&\in {\mathbb R}^{256\times 256\times 256\times 256} \\
}$$
where ${\Omega}$ is the fourth-order tensor which acts as 
the identity for the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
{\Omega}:S = S:{\Omega} = S \\
}$$
and its components can be expressed in terms of Kronecker delta symbols
$$\eqalign{
{\Omega}_{ijk\ell} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}
}$$
The action of the tensor Hessian on a matrix $B$ is calculated as 
$$\eqalign{
{\cal H}:B 
&= ({\Omega} + K_2^TK_2{\Omega}K_1^TK_1):B \\
&= B + K_2^TK_2BK_1^TK_1 \\
\\
}$$
**NB:** $\;$ The elements of the tensor ${\cal H}$ are 
*exactly the same* as those of the matrix $H$, they're just 
arranged differently. Neither solves your memory issue, since they're 
both equally huge.

The factored form in the comments does address the storage issue. 
Each of the three Kronecker factors is a $256\times 256$ matrix.

Comment: I don't want to use kronecker product because $ K_1$ and $ K_2 $ are too large for common PC.  Does the matrix form of the hessian equal to $$ \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{S}}=K_1K_2K_1^TK_2^T $$

Comment: If it helps, you can work with it in factored form
$$\eqalign{
&H = I\otimes I + (K_1^TK_1)\otimes(K_2^TK_2) \\
&{\rm where}\quad I,\,(K_1^TK_1),\,(K_2^TK_2) \in{\mathbb R}^{256\times 256}
}$$
Then the action of the hessian on a matrix  $B$ can be calculated as
$$H{\rm vec}(B) \to B + (K_2^TK_2)B(K_1^TK_1)$$

Comment: $$ G=S + K_2^TAK_1\\
\eqalign{dG &= S:dS + K_2^TAK_1:dA \\
 &= S:dS +  K_2^TAK_1:(K_2K_1^T)dS \\
 &= S:dS + K_1K_2^TK_2^TAK_1:dS \\
 &= (I + K_1K_2^TK_2^TAK_1):dS\\
 
 Hessian = I + K_1K_2^TK_2^TAK_1
 }$$

Comment: Is there any alterlative for  hessian matrix during optimization? These matrices are too large for PC.

Comment: Your hessian calculation is wrong. I've updated the answer with the full tensor calculation. If you can't make the hessian work, switch to a gradient-based optimization method, e.g. Barzilia-Borwein, Conjugate Gradients, etc.

Comment: Is there any alterlative for hessian matrix during optimization? "These matrices are too large for PC." L-BFGS, which requires much less storage than for Hessian..